# Deleting a closed question

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

- What happens with your rep if you delete a question that was closed previously?
- Do you lose rep points?

I deleted a question that I asked in **[`Unix & Linux`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)** that was downvoted `(-2)`, and I regained `+4` rep. But I deleted a post that was closed, and I think I lost about 2 points.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a threshold. If a post is deleted that has more than [3 upvotes and has been visible for more than 60 days](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), there is no change in reputation. Else there is.

Also, deleting of community wiki posts have no effect on reputation.